# How can i validate the font family of a html object?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to get to validat a font family of an object. Here is the code

```
        HtmlDocument editorAfter = Browser.Find<HtmlDocument>("FriendlyName~Rich text editor, ctl00_ContentBodyPlaceHolder__An...;Class=cke_show_borders");
        string TextVanEditoreAfter = editorAfter.ControlDefinition;
        Assert.IsTrue(TextVanEditoreAfter.Contains("font-family=\"Arial, Verdana, sans-serif"));
```

But the Controle definition does not extract the proprty font family. So the Assert always fails. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the rendered html from that web page?

Comment: also curious are you actually getting your rich text editor? depens on the search criteria it might be getting the top level doc for the whole webpage